# can't view array objects using ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I am pretty new to angular and trying to build a small app with rails as backend. I am trying to iterate over an array of objects and display them on the view though somehow I don't seem to be able to get around this. There is definitely something stupid I am missing here.

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('WoWiWe')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$http',
  '$scope',
  'wishFactory',
  function($scope, wishFactory, wishesPromise){
    $scope.wishesJson = [{
      text: "Standard Message"
      }, {
      text: "Success Message!",
      type: "success"
      }, {
      text: "Alert Message!",
      type: "alert"
      }, {
      text: "secondary message...",
      type: "secondary"
    }];

  console.log($scope.wishesJson);
}]);
```

and my html partial looks like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-repeat="wi in wishesJson">
  <p> {{wi.text}} </p>
  <h5>Rewishes <span class="badge">3</span> </h5>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a type="button" class="btn-sm btn-success" ng-href="#/">Fulfill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></a>
    <a type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" ng-href="#" ng-click="incrementRewishCount(wish)">Rewish <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span></a>
    <a type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger" ng-href="#/">Flag <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span></a>
    <span>
      <a href="#/conversation/some">Messages</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<form ng-submit="addWish()" style="margin-top: 30px">
  <h4>Make a new wish</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your wish" ng-model="wishTitle"></input>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Small description" ng-model="wishDesc"></input>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

I also have a config block in a separate file to tie things together:

```
angular.module('WoWiWe', ['ui.router', 'templates'])

.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      resolve: {
        wishesPromise: ['wishFactory', function(w) {
          return w.getAll();
        }]
      },
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('conversation', {
       url: '/conversation/{id}',
       templateUrl: 'conversation/_conversation.html',
       controller: 'ConversationCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}]);
```

I can see the $scope.wishesJson on console but the ng-repeat tag does not inflate views on my webpage
I've browsed a lot over the internet and this seems to be too trivial an issue which I am not able to catch.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you show your entire code on jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: I don't see any errors. The browser just renders the form and nothing else.
I'll share a fiddle in a moment

Comment: jsfiddle link, I've omitted some embedded ruby code and consolidated codes from different files https://jsfiddle.net/prateekkarkare/rhwff2oe/2/#&togetherjs=65uUKTeQBT